# QGIS how to prevent label text from wrapping

Tags: qgis, labeling

I have a polygon layer and am using single labels with an expression that creates a three line label using three fields:
Label expression: "name" ||  '\n'  || "report" ||   '\n'  || "depth"

For some reason text wrapping is happening for the third line (depth field). The first two lines are not wrapping (name and report fields). I don't want text wrapping.
(QGIS version 3.30.2)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your `depth` field has line breaks in the data itself (you can test this by typing `"depth"` in the Expression Dialog box; you would see the text with line breaks in the Preview section below).

If that is the case, you would need to strip out the linebreaks from the `depth` field, by using `replace("depth",'\n','')` instead of just `"depth"` .

Comment: Solved!! Great stuff - that has done the job!!! Thanks!